# How to make pulseaudio activity dictate sleep state (Caffeine workaround)

Tags: ubuntu, sleep, pulse-audio

I would like my monitor to go off if inactive after an hour per settings, despite if caffeine is running. However, I would like this action to be null if pulseaudio detects any audio playing. Is this possible? I am running ubuntu 16 LTS. Thank you for any insight in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for any sinks feeding to an output in pulseaudio which would 'ideally' do what you want, however it'll have the oddity of if an application is playing while muted (such as you muted the youtube video) I believe that'd still count as 'playing'.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61337/testing-from-a-script-if-audio-devices-are-in-silent

Shows how to test for it, basically you'd need to build a wrapper script around calling xscreensaver (or whatever you call to blank your monitor) and use the check in the above answer.

This would look something like this:

```
if [[`pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep -c 'state: RUNNING'`]]
    call xscreensaver
fi;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I have checked it out (around when you posted it) and have been trying to wrap my head around that page. Unfortunately it was a little advanced for me to comprehend right now. I have done further research since and investigated alternative branches of caffeine with a patch to no avail, and can't even get caffeine to launch on start. I guess I was hoping for a nice gui implementation or a caffeine plugin or something. Is there any way you could further break down the guide you provided or is there any alternative you know of? I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: For example, what is a "sink" when it comes to computers?